# Check for clock skews on machines where I can only submit jobs

Tags: linux, shell-script, remote, clock

I need to check for a clock skew in many remote machines. What is the best way to check for a clock skew on a Linux machine?

I don't need to sync clocks, just to check how accurate it is. I don't have root on those machines. I don't have direct access there, I just can submit jobs there. I think all machines have NTP configured, but could use different servers.

I need to write a simple, robust bash script for that.

Comment: What sort of access do you have to those machines (ssh, ...)? Is there an NTP server running on those machines (e.g., ntpd) and serving network clients (IP Port UDP/123)?

Comment: I don't have direct access there, I just can submit jobs there. I think all machines have NTP configured, but could use different servers.

Comment: If the machines are running `ntpd` for time synchronisation, and allow access from other machines, you could try to configure your local machine's `ntpd` to use them as time servers. Then `ntpq -p` will show you the different delays.